# looping through mySQL json_encode with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm struggling to retrieve and display results from PHP json_encode via JQuery. Any help appreciated. Here's my code php side:

```
$return_it = array();
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");        
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$row_array[] = $row;
array_push($return_it,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_it);
```

and on success I have this.

```
dataType: 'json',  
success: function(data)         
 {
    $.each(data, function() {
    var name = data.name;           
    var values = data.values;           
       $('#output').append("<tr style=\"background-color:#ccc\"><td>id: </td><td> name: </td></tr><tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+values+"</td></tr>"); 
    }); 
}
```

this is looping but returning undefined, I know I'm probably missing something obvious :-/

Comment: tip: `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. user `mysqli` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array nesting in php is unnecessary and doesn't match the way you are trying to parse the results. Just use the `return_it` array for each row

```
$return_it = array();
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");        
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $return_it[] = $row;
    //array_push($return_it,$row_array); /* remove */
}
echo json_encode($return_it);
```

The result in javascript currently would look like

```
[ 
   [ {name:'foo',values:'123'} ],
   [ {name:'foo2',values:'345'} ]
]
```

Without the extra nesting:

```
[ 
    {name:'foo',values:'123'},
    {name:'foo2',values:'345'}
]
```

This will not change the `$.each` parsing, rather you would need to look inside each sub array if maintain current structure.
You are however misisng critical arguments for `$.each` callback

```
$.each(data, function() {index, row){
    var name = row.name;
 });
```

Comment: Well spoted @charlietfl.

Comment: I have Data :)  thanks very much both of you, @Nikos and charliefl. as you said I was missing the arguments  

   $.each(data, function(index,row){
   var name = row.name;
   var values = row.values;

did the trick. Many thanks again for your help!!

Trev

Comment: No problem :). To be fair, @charlietfl found the key issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
dataType: 'json',  
success: function(data)         
 {
    $.each(data, function(d) {
    var name = d[0].name;           
   var values = d[0].values;           
     $('#output').append("<tr style=\"background-color:#ccc\"><td>id: </td><td> name:   </td></tr><tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+values+"</td></tr>"); 
}); 
}
```

The `each` method applies a method to each element that is passed to the method. As it happens, you are not passing anything to `function()`, so you should add the parameter (in my example it is `d`) and manipulate `d`, rather than `data`.

As apparently you are nesting the json array (returing an array of single arrays) the `d[0]` part would return the attributes of the first element of your nested array, which, in your case would be your `{name:"...",values:"..."}`.

However, if you remove your nested JSON array as mentioned in another answer, then you don't need to add the `d[0].name`, and use only `d.name` as now each line of your JSON array is the collection of attributes, rather than an array of size 1, which would have the attributes.

Essentially you are encapsoulating your results. You should either remove the encapsoulation, or adjust the data parsing from JSON.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice as well ,-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but 'd' isn't defined anywhere, it's definitely how I'm retrieving the data though.

Comment: @Trev Hi, sorry did you manage to solve it? The `d` is an argument to the function(). It will be each line of data. Unless I am confusing you.. Sorry :)

Comment: no, added the parameter (apologies for my haste in replying before) but still undefined.

Comment: 'name' and 'values' are the column names. is that the correct call?

Comment: Can you post the first 5 lines of your JSON output please?

Comment: @Trev your php source structure doesn't match the `$.each` code

Comment: charlietfl is right. I have edited my code, could you have a look now? Otherwise you should follow charlietfl's well defined answer below.

Comment: @Nikos thanks to you and charlietfl for your help. I've altered it php side all fine but changing to d[0].name; etc returns no results. could you explain the logic of this Nikos? thank you again for your help